# Pivot table -/+ aggregation

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble with the below query. I need to find the percentage increase or decrease between years for enrollment.  For some reason I'm getting multiple line items and my output is incorrect.  The script runs fine but produces incorrect results

script:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( SELECT    DISTINCT
                                    dt.YEAR ,
                                    db.business_code ,
                                    db.business_name ,
                                    dt.time_key ,
                                    fes.total_enrollment
                          FROM     fact
                                    AS fes
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN building
                                    AS db ON fes.building_key = db.building_key
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mart.time
                                    AS dt ON fes.time_key = dt.time_key

                        ) AS source PIVOT
    ( sum(total_enrollment) FOR [year] IN ( [2012], [2011], [2010], [2009],
                                            [2008] ) ) as pvt
             )
    SELECT  company_code ,
            company_name ,
            [2012] ,
            ( CASE WHEN [2011] <> 0
                   THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2012] - [2011] )
                        / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2011] ))) * 100
              END ) AS '% Degree -/+' ,

            [2011] ,
            ( CASE WHEN [2010] <> 0
                   THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2011] - [2010] )
                        / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2010] ))) * 100
              END ) AS '% Degree -/+' ,
            [2010] ,
            ( CASE WHEN [2009] <> 0
                   THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2010] - [2009] )
                        / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2009] ))) * 100
              END ) AS '% Degree -/+' ,
            [2009] ,
            ( CASE WHEN [2008] <> 0
                   THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2009] - [2008] )
                        / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), ( [2008] ))) * 100

              END 
              ) AS '% Degree -/+'
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY company_name
```

Heres my SQL output:
[image]

Here is my desired output:
[image]

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Did you try throwing a `MAX` around the columns in the final select and a `group by company_code, company_name`?

Comment: i have tried your suggestion and Im still getting the same results

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle with your tables and some sample data?